# Reduce a Weibull model to an exponential one

Tags: distributions, self-study, weibull-distribution

I have this problem:

Let $\ X\sim Weibull(\theta_1;\theta_2)$

with the sample:

```
31.02, 14.57, 42.6, 67.73, 65.72, 79.76, 5.4, 32.35, 63.08, 17.27, 23.71, 9.65,  
8.11, 18.94, 22.27, 5.87, 25.9, 28.99, 40.17, 29.74, 30.49, 29.65, 69.45, 35.42,   
33.33, 26.92, 86.23, 57.33, 97.34, 24.33, 77.85, 10.48, 49.41, 58.24, 84.78, 35.44
```

I estimated $\ \theta_1$ and $\ \theta_2$ in R with the MLE method:

$\ \tilde\theta_1 = 1.6426$
$\ \tilde\theta_2 = 0.0019$

and their 95% confidence intervals:

$\ \theta_1 \in [1.2174;2.0666]$

$\ \theta_2 \in [-0.0015;0.0054]$

I'm asked to determine if the proposed Weibull model can be reduced/simplified to an exponential one using the above results. How do I go about doing this? I know that $\ X\sim Weibull(1;\theta_2)=exp(\theta_2)$ but I don't know where to go from there or if that even helps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one way to decide would be to see if the interval for the relevant parameter included the value that parameter takes at the exponential.

An alternative would be to do a likelihood ratio test (in large samples the results should be quite similar).

[However, outside bookwork, I would generally say avoid formal testing of model assumptions as a method of model choice; it's not as important whether you can formally reject exponentiality (in any sufficiently large sample you probably will, since perfectly exponential data is unlikely) as whether an exponential model will be adequate for your purposes. Or as George Box put it in a different incarnation of his famous saying, "*Remember that all models are wrong; the practical question is how wrong do they have to be to not be useful.*"]

Comment: I've read up on the likelihood ratio test and it was the right way to approach this. Thanks for the insight as well!

Comment: I think that non-parametric distribution fitting (such as `MASS::fitdistr()`) could be an another alternative approach in this case. Am I right?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh `fitdistr` is parametric. Nonparametric would be something like `stats::density` or `logspline::logspline`. I also don't see how it quite solves the problem of deciding between a Weibull a special case of the Weibull.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. My thoughts became blurred between use of non-parametric functions for mixture analysis (`mixtools` package) and reading on [non-parametric kernel distribution function estimation](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v50/i08/paper) (`kerdiest` package). I've already figured that *kernel distribution function* differs from *probability density function*. I'm quite overwhelmed with all the info and feel the need to make some order from chaos in the statistical part of my brain. As for Weibull -> exp, I didn't mean it as direct solution to the OP, just as a related topic.